# Fatou lemma and weak convergence in Hilbert

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

In a Hilbert space $H$ a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ is said to converge weakly to $x$ if $\forall y\in H:\langle y,x_n\rangle\rightarrow\langle y,x\rangle$, the case in which we can easily deduce an inequality:
$$|x|\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{m\geq n}|x_m|$$
by Schwartz inequality.
Is there any connection between this inequality and Fatou's lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a connection between Fatou's lemma and the mentioned result on weak convergence when the considered Hilbert space is separable. The idea is to write norms in terms of sums of squares of inner products and use the counting measure.

More concretely, take a Hilbert basis $\left(e_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ and define a measure   on $X:= \{ e_i,i\geqslant 1\}$  by $\mu\{e_i\}=1$ for each $i\geqslant 1 $. Define on $X$ the map $f_n(y):=\langle x_n,y\rangle$. Then $f_n(y)\to f(y)$ on $X$ and by Fatou's lemma, $\lVert f\rVert_2\leqslant \liminf_{n\to + \infty}  \lVert f_n\rVert_2$. Now we conclude using Bessel-Parseval equality.